# 7: [unixODBC][DataDirect][ODBC 20101 driver]6015 error

Tags: odbc, unixodbc

For our application we have planned to use the Progress Data Direct ODBC driver for oracle. So i have downloaded the EVAL version and installed it. Our application servers are running in the Linux environment.
  After installing the EVAL version i have tested the sample code provided by them. I have configured the ODBC.INI and ODBCINST.INI properly.
  Tested the DSN connection successfully with the sample program provided by DataDirect Progress. 
  Then i started using the same for my application Lib LD path set properly ODBC , ODBCINST variables are properly set.
  when i try to bring up my servers i got the below error message

```
7: [unixODBC][DataDirect][ODBC 20101 driver]6015
```

In this message i'm not getting the message description , only i got the error code which is 6015

How to get the error message for this code 6015 ?
Any help on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the older version of driver got the error , so installed newer version and it got resolved.